# A custom loss function which weights the loss depending on the age of data used

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions, weighted-regression, time-complexity

I was wondering if it is possible to weight the loss so that old data are evaluated less than new data.

Lets say I have a product which has a trend in value spanning across decades, I want the model to weigh new data much higher than old data. Since old data might be misleading according to current prices.

Is this done through the loss-function or am i missing something obvious? If you know of anyone else who have looked into something similar then pointing me in that direction is greatly appreciated!

Happy holidays, stay safe!

Comment: Do you have time series data? So something like an AR or MA process?

Comment: Unfortunately it isnt time-series data. So i only have 1 data-point for each product. The data i am looking at is house-sales. So i have one point for when a house was last sold. Some houses are sold 10 years ago, some a sold yesterday. I want my model to value a house sold yesterday higher that a house sold 10 years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have historical data so i can't create a time-series dataset.

Comment: In a linear regression, this can be done via weighted least squares (WLS) estimation. The `lm` function in R offers this functionality. A *very crude* but pretty general way to make it work for any method is replicate the data points so that there are more replicas of new points and fewer (maybe just one) of older ones.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy! I will look into WLS maybe its something i can implement. I would rather not have replica data points but i will test it out and see what it does to my model :)

Comment: @DitlevJørgensen, yeah, I would probably not do it the crude way myself unless I was desperate :) But it could work for rough testing or for illustratives purposes.